# Nice exercises on resultants

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials

I would like to ask if some one knows a source (a book, or lecture notes ect) that contains several nice exercises on resultants of polynomials (it would be nice if there were some solutions as well but if not this is ok)

I would like to stress, that I am looking for a large collection of exercises (say 10-30), I would like to chose a couple of them to give to students in a class. If possible, I would avoid exercises related to number theory. On the contrary, exercises related to algebraic geometry would be especially appreciated.

Comment: [Here](https://brilliant.org/i/IDQeND/) is a problem that you can try. It will be helpful if you can further specify the extent of knowledge of resultants that you are looking at.

Comment: I you don't use  resultants the answer is  $f(i\sqrt 2)\cdot f(-i \sqrt)$ where f is the polynimial? I guess, I want some problems that are the most easily solved if you know resultants.

Comment: I use resultants (too?-)frequently, and have referenced them fairly often here. See [this search](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A409+resultant) (which, unfortunately also includes hits for "result" and "results" and "resulting") of my answers involving them; the corresponding questions may be of interest to you (or not ... I don't really remember them all :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two algebraic geometry books that talk about resultants.

1)
Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra  [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387946802)
Chapter 3, section 6.

2) 
Introduction to Algebraic Geometry [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387946802)
Chapter 5.

Each book has 10-20 problems about resultants.

Answer (score 2):

> Let $L/K$ be a field extension, $a,b \in L$ algebraic over $K$ with minimal polynomials $f \neq g$. Prove that $N_{K(a)/K}(g(a)) = (-1)^{\deg(f) \deg(g)} N_{K(b)/K}(f(b))$.

I don't even know how this can be done without resultants (and without pain).

Comment: Martin thanks! I still wonder if there is a book that contains various exercises on resultants

Answer (score 0):

Recently I became aware of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821893963) book. Although I haven't read it, I believe it contains what you need. Specifically, resultants are treated on §3 (Bezout's theorem) of the 3rd chapter and there are about 20-30 exercises (with solutions I believe).